# Triggering a ActionResult method off of a checkbox toggle

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm a semi-competent Winforms/WPF/MVVM/c#/vb.Net dev, attempting to teach myself ASP.Net with MVC and i'm a little confused as to how you "raise events" (i know MVC doesn't do events but that's what i'm equating it to) off of anything that's not a form's submit button. I have a View, Controller and a Model for a simple to-do list style application and i'm wondering how i can trigger some code in the controller off of the toggling of the check box. This is my code:

View (Views/ToDo/Index.cshtml):

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@model List<ToDo.Models.ToDoListItem>
<h2>To Do List</h2>

<form action="/ToDo/Create" method="post">
    <div>
        <input name="ToDoItem" />
        <input type="submit" value="Add Task" />
    </div>
</form>


<div>
    <ul>
        @if (Model != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <li>
                    <form action="/ToDo/Delete/@item.ItemId " method="post"> 
                        <input type="checkbox" checked="@item.isChecked" />
                        @if (item.isCompleted)
                        {
                            <label style="text-decoration-line:line-through">@item.ItemText</label>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <label>@item.ItemText</label>
                        }
                        <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
                    </form>
                </li>
            }
        }

    </ul>
</div>
```

Controller (Controllers/ToDoController.cs):

```
namespace ToDo.Controllers
{
    public class ToDoController : Controller
    {
        // GET: ToDo
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(Models.ToDoListItem.GetAll());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(string toDoItem)
        {
            Models.ToDoListItem.Create(toDoItem, Models.ToDoListItem.GetNextID());
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(string id)
        {
            int itemIdentifier = Convert.ToInt32(id);
            Models.ToDoListItem.Delete(itemIdentifier);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CheckBoxToggle(string id)
        {
            int itemIdentifier = Convert.ToInt32(id);
            Models.ToDoListItem.CompleteToggeled(itemIdentifier);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Model (Models/ToDiListItem.cs):

```
namespace ToDo.Models
{
    public class ToDoListItem 
    {
        #region Fields

        private int _itemId;
        private string _itemText;
        private bool _isCompleted;

        #endregion

        #region Events

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        public int ItemId
        {
            get
            {
                return _itemId;
            }
            set
            {
                _itemId = value;
            }
        }

        public string ItemText
        {
            get
            {
                return _itemText;
            }
            set
            {
                _itemText = value;
            }
        }

        public bool isCompleted
        {
            get
            {
                return _isCompleted;
            }
            set
            {
                _isCompleted = value;
            }
        }

        public string isChecked
        {
            get
            {
                if (isCompleted)
                    return "checked";
                else
                    return string.Empty;
            }
        }
        #endregion


        #region Public Methods

        public static void Create(string toDoItem, int itemId)
        {
            var item = new ToDoListItem();
            item.ItemText = toDoItem;
            item.ItemId = itemId;

            GlobalVariables.Tasks.Add(item);
        }

        public static void Delete(int id)
        {
            foreach (ToDoListItem item in GlobalVariables.Tasks)
            {
                if (item.ItemId == id)
                {
                    GlobalVariables.Tasks.Remove(item);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        public static void CompleteToggeled(int id)
        {
            foreach (ToDoListItem item in GlobalVariables.Tasks)
            {
                if (item.ItemId == id)
                {
                    item.isCompleted = !item.isCompleted;
                }
            }
        }

        public static List<ToDoListItem> GetAll()
        {
            return GlobalVariables.Tasks;
        }

        public static int GetNextID()
        {
            return ++GlobalVariables.CurrentID;
        }

        #endregion

    }

}
```

So, what i am looking to do, is to be able to toggle the "checked" state one of the checkboxes on the form and call the "CheckBoxToggle" method in my controller, passing in the ID of the item (similarly to how i did it on the delete button). I've seen something to do with Javascript (which i know nothing about) being mentioned, but i have no real idea what i am doing with it and nothing i've seen so far explains it particularly clearly.

If anyone knows the best way for me to go about this, some assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the `change` event on the checkbox and **post the form** which includes an input form element with same name as your HttpPost action method parameter.

Update your markup so that it will have a css class which we will use as our jQuery selector for wiring up the event listener for the checbox toggle event. Also you can keep the Id of item in an input hidden field with same name as your parameter (`Id`)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CheckBoxToggle", "Todo"))
{
  <input type="checkbox" class="myChk" name="isChecked" checked="checked"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@item.Id" />
}
```

Now basically you need to listen to the click event on the check box.

```
$(function(){

   $(".myChk").click(function() {
         $(this).closest("form").submit();
   });

});
```

*Assuming you have jQuery library loaded to your page.*

I also see you are receiving the parameter value in string and converting it back to int. Why not use the int type param ? You may also add one more parameterr named isChecked to know whether user checked the checkbox or unchecked. When it is checked the parameter value will be **not null**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CheckBoxToggle(int id,string isChecked)
{
    Models.ToDoListItem.CompleteToggeled(id);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```